# PRESTASHOP - how to show regular and discounted prices in basket summary after discount code is used

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

**Problem**

On order item list in basket summary there is no final price of one single product after using any voucher/discount code. There is just total amount of discount value in summary.

Default behavior is that discount amount is calculated and show as total amount (not showing a discount value for each product).
So in cart summary we have:

```
product X - price 10,00$
product Y - price 20,00$
product Z - price 2,00$
```

and we use the code lets say: **gimme20** - that gives 20% discount
So in basket summary it looks like:

```
product X - price 10,00$
product Y - price 20,00$
product Z - price 2,00$

code: gimme20
total: 32,00$
discount: 6,40$
to pay: 25,60$
```

and we need to show in summary (**solution we'd like**):

```
product X - price 10,00$ after discount-> 8,00$
product Y - price 20,00$ after discount-> 16,00$
product Z - price 2,00$ after discount-> 1,60$
code: gimme20
total: 32,00$
discount: 6,40$
to pay: 25,60$
```

So it is strange that is not working like that by default.

We need to pass each product final discounted price to ERP.

How to do that?
Do we need to recalculate every item price extra or is Presta keeping that value somewhere.
It is cart summary so we have `$cart` object available to use.

Comment: There is possibly a hook for `displayCartAfter` you could use. Not sure with 1.6 though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in PrestaShop, creating a discount for the entire order does not apply the discount to each item separately, but to the entire order amount.
This is something that causes many problems, especially when we want to generate an invoice based on an order, where in the invoicing program the only option is to apply a discount to the item on the invoice.

Therefore, to solve your problem, you have to calculate the amounts individually when downloading the order to the ERP. Watch out for missing pennies in calculations because it always causes trouble. For example, if the order amount is €100 and there are 3 products in the basket and a 10% discount code, then 10%/3 = 3.33333333333(3) so two products will have a price reduced by €3.33 and one €3.34, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, thank you for a tip. But how to recognise what product should be discounted and what if discount is not percentage but strict amount. I quess I have to make an array or object of products that can be discounted with specific code.

Comment: in the discount code settings, you can set it to apply it to selected products, but I would advise against such a thing due to the amount of extra work in creating codes. However, if there was such a need (e.g. a discount for a specific product), then the code can be limited to this product, and when downloading the order to the ERP, check whether the discount code calculated had any restrictions. If so, use an algorithm appropriate to these constraints.